# Javascript Function Not Being Used in RGB fill Style

Tags: javascript

The randomColorValue function in fillStyle is not being used. The canvas is just being painted all black instead of the random color scheme. I am a bit of a beginner and hope this isn't a complete noob question or something just plain obvious. Thanks for any help. I italicized the most relevant code.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('squares');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
for (let x = 0; x <=800; x+=50){
 for(let y= 0; y<=800; y+=50){
 ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${randomColorValue()},${randomColorValue()},${randomColorValue()})`;
 ctx.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
}
function randomColorValue(){
 let actualValue = Math.ceil (Math.random*255);
return actualValue; 
}
```

Comment: You forgot `()`, it should be `let actualValue = Math.ceil (Math.random()*255);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure why I sometimes miss obvious formatting like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Math.random` to `Math.random()`. When fillStyle has non RGB-value as the input, it will turn black instead and `Math.random` is a function.

Tested, it works [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbptfxfa)

Answer (score 0):

It actually does, but it's failing silently. The `randomColorValue` returns a `NaN`, because `Math.random` is a function, and you don't call it. Your `randomColorValue` should look like this:

```js
function randomColorValue() {
  let actualValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 255);
  return actualValue; 
}
```

and it will work :)